# How to display multiple html pages using single index.html

Tags: html

I have multiple html pages and i want to display them all using a index.html, but i don't want to use any link button or any thing. I want to display them after a time period. How can i do so?

Comment: What technologies are you using? If it's only html, it's impossible. You can use PHP or JS-AJAX to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta tag in every page header. and inside the meta tag you can put your redirect link and time.

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
```

This is the time in second.

```
content="5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this . For every individual HTML page you have to put this code and redirect it to the next html page .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
  },60000)
</script>
```